# Does a table cell border count as part of its content?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

The following document renders differently on Firefox and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table rendering test</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
            table td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            tr.testRow > td {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            tr.testRow table {
                border-color: #ff0000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>cell1.1</td>
                <td>cell1.2</td>
                <td>cell1.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="testRow">
                <td>cell2.1</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>internal table cell</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Firefox:
[image: Fx rendering]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome rendering]

Note how Firefox does not count the bottom-right cell's border as part of its content, so the "internal table" renders 1 pixel to the right of the border of the above cell.  Chrome, however, renders the "internal table" at the same horizontal location as the above cell's border.

Both of these browsers are operating in standards mode.  Which browser is exhibiting the correct behaviour?  And how can I modify the code so that they both exhibit the behaviour Chrome is giving (which is what I want)?

Answer (score 1):

**Which browser is exhibiting the correct behaviour?**

Technically, both are behaving correctly.

They're each interpreting the specification in their own way and also have different ways of compiling and rendering a page to your screen.

**How can I modify the code so that they both exhibit the behaviour Chrome is giving?**

Using the CSS property `box-sizing`.

If you set this too `border-box`, it will always include padding and the border into the width of an element.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.with_sizing {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">This is a box with no box sizing</div>
<div class="box with_sizing">This is a box with box sizing</div>
```

Have a look at both of the above boxes and you will see that the top element only has the content at 200px and then adds the border and padding on top whereas the element below, which has `box-sizing: border-box` set will have the entire area set to 200px.

Comment: What does `box-sizing` have to do with *where* the browser renders the internal table?  I'm not talking about its size.

Comment: Your question states the border isn't being counted in the content and isnt rendering as expected. I would hazard a guess at this being a box sizing issue. The other alternative being the browser's built in CSS is rendering that way. Either way the functionality is not "incorrect" but just how each browser deals with different elements.